# Hls play only audio, but video is black

Tags: streaming, rtmp, hls.js

I have an application that uses rtmp nginx for streaming. Configure hls_time 1s. Sometimes when I refresh hls player, it only plays audio and video shows black. I used OBS for streaming with keyframe 2s).

Answer (score 0):

I saw that someone said "Segments will be clipped at keyframes, so unless a keyframe exists every second, hls_time will not be accepted.". So I changed the keyframe 1s and it worked fine.